# Ruby background: What are linked lists?

Tags: ruby, data-structures

I'm a self taught programmer and started off with Ruby. I'm currently trying to learn algorithms and data structures and noticed something called a linked list. It looks like Ruby doesn't have that data structure (maybe in Array?). I'm familiar with arrays and hashes.

How would you describe/explain what a linked list is for someone coming from my background?

Comment: I'm almost positive linked lists are described both at a high level, and in exhausting detail,  on hundreds of websites.

Comment: http://matt.weppler.me/2013/08/14/implementing-a-linked-list-in-ruby.html

Comment: I just started a series on mastering data structures in ruby. And the first post is, of course, about linked lists. You can check it out on my blog: https://medium.com/amiralles/mastering-data-structures-in-ruby-linked-lists-708347a30360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In computer science, a linked list is a data structure consisting of a group of nodes which together represent a sequence. Under the simplest form, each node is composed of a data and a reference (in other words, a link) to the next node in the sequence; more complex variants add additional links. This structure allows for efficient insertion or removal of elements from any position in the sequence.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Here is a implementation on ruby: http://matt.weppler.me/2013/08/14/implementing-a-linked-list-in-ruby.html

Kudos for studying Ruby one of my favorites languages.

Answer (score 2):

Linked lists are rather simple: they are lists which are created by linking the elements together. (Kind of obvious, when you think about it, no?)

In its most basic form, a linked list is simply either empty or a pair. The first element of the pair is a value, and the second element of the pair is a linked list representing the rest of the values.

Traditionally, the pair is called a *cons cell*, the first element is called the *head* or the *car* of the list and the second element is called the *tail* or the *cdr* of the list. The empty list is called `Nil` or simply `[]`.

Here is an extremely simple implementation of a linked list in Ruby, which uses nothing but functions to implement a linked list (and booleans and conditionals, while we're at it):

```
True   = ->(iff, _) { iff }
False  = ->(_, els) { els }

Pair   = ->(first, rest) { -> x { x.(first, rest) }}
First  = -> list { list.(True ) }
Rest   = -> list { list.(False) }
```

Here, we have a simple list with three elements:

```
List   = Pair.(1, Pair.(2, Pair.(3, nil)))

First.(Rest.(List))
# => 2
```

A more realistic object-oriented encoding of a list looks like this:

```
class List
  def cons(el) Pair.new(el, self) end

  Empty = new

  class Pair < self
    attr_reader :first, :rest

    def initialize(first, rest=Empty)
      self.first, self.rest = first, rest
    end

    private

    attr_writer :first, :rest
  end
end
```

Again, a list with two elements:

```
list1 = List::Pair.new(1, List::Pair.new(2, List::Pair.new(3, List::Empty)))
# corresponds to the list [1, 2, 3]

list1.rest.first
# => 2

list2 = List::Empty.cons(6).cons(5).cons(4)
# List[4, 5, 6]

list2.rest.first
# => 5
```

A more complete and Rubyish implementation might look like this:

```
class List
  include Enumerable

  def self.[](*els) els.reverse_each.inject(Empty, &:cons) end

  def cons(el) Pair[el, self] end

  def prepend(prefix)
    case
    when        empty? then prefix
    when prefix.empty? then self
    else prepend(prefix.rest).cons(prefix.first)
    end
  end

  def to_s; "List[#{map(&:to_s).join(', ')}]" end
  def inspect; "List[#{map(&:inspect).join(', ')}]" end

  def each; return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given? end

  class << Empty = new
    def empty?; true end
    alias_method :inspect, def to_s; 'Empty' end

    freeze
  end
  Empty.freeze

  class Pair < self
    def initialize(first, rest=Empty)
      self.first, self.rest = first, rest
      freeze
    end

    def empty?; false end

    def each(&blk)
      return super unless block_given?
      yield first
      rest.each(&blk)
    end

    private
    attr_writer :first, :rest

    protected
    attr_reader :first, :rest

    class << self; alias_method :[], :new end

    freeze
  end

  freeze
end
```

Some examples:

```
list1 = List::Pair[1, List::Pair[2, List::Pair[3, List::Empty]]]
# => List[1, 2, 3]

list2 = List::Empty.cons(6).cons(5).cons(4)
# => List[4, 5, 6]

list3 = List[7, 8, 9]
# => List[7, 8, 9]

list4 = list3.prepend(list2).prepend(list1)
# => List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

list4.partition(&:odd?)
# => [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```